# Extract nth occurence of tag and the content from XML file

Tags: xml, shell, unix

I have a an XML file with this data:

```
<server>
    <servername>server1</servername>
    <userid>user1</userid>
    <passw>pass1</passw>
    <dbname>dbname1</dbname>
</server>
<server>
    <servername>server2</servername>
    <userid>user2</userid>
    <passw>pass2</passw>
    <dbname>dbname2</dbname>
</server>
<server>
    <servername>server3</servername>
    <userid>user3</userid>
    <passw>pass3</passw>
    <dbname>dbname3</dbname>
</server>
<server>
    <servername>server4</servername>
    <userid>user4</userid>
    <passw>pass4</passw>
    <dbname>dbname4</dbname>
</server>
```

I want to extract the information from the file for each server. I'm to extract the details for all together, but how to extract for n<sup>th</sup> occurrence of the server tag?

Comment: are you trying to do this using shell script? or open to using an xml parser?

Comment: post how should look the extracted info

Comment: Yeah, I’m trying to use a shell script to extract the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the structure of the XML file is that simple and you can rely on consistency, I'd probably reach for an awk one-liner.  For instance:

```
cat servers.xml | awk -v n=3 '{ if ($1 == "<server>") i++; if (i == n) print $0 }'
```

Would result in:

```
<server>
    <servername>server3</servername>
    <userid>user3</userid>
    <passw>pass3</passw>
    <dbname>dbname3</dbname>
</server>
```

Adjust **n=3** to match the number of the iteration you wish to extract.